# Computing a Finite Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

**Assume $1\leq\ k<m<n$ are positive integers and $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are i.i.d. Geometric($p$) random variables. For all $j\geq\ k$ define $I_j=[(i_1,i_2,...,i_k):1\leq\ i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq\ j]$. 
Define $S_j=\sum\ _{(i_1,i_2,...,i_k)\in\ I_j}ln(2+(X_{i_1})^3+(X_{i_2})^3+...+(X_{i_k})^3)$
Show that $S_m/S_n$ has finite expectation and compute this expectation.**

So this is the question. I cannot figure out why this question needed to be so artificial, not to add that I am facing difficulty in solving this. Please treat this as a homework question and give me some hints and not the complete solution.

Comment: May be the last one should be $X_{i_k}$. Then, Can you see that each term in the sum $S_m$ is also present in $S_n$?

Comment: Indeed. Finiteness of expectation is not at all difficult to prove. But any hint in actually computing the expectation?

Comment: Hint: If $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_r$ are equal in distribution and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r} Z_i=C$ where $C$ is a constant then $E(Z_i)=\frac{C}{r}$ for all $i$. This should help.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, as I may be. After analyzing your hint, I note that since $S_n/S_n=1$ we have $E(S_n/S_n)=1$ and then by i.i.d. property, we have $E(ln(2+X_1^3+X_2^3+...+X_k^3)/S_n)=1/nCk$.
So, $E(S_m/S_n)=mCk/nCk.$